# On screen car detection on Android

Tags: android, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo, google-mlkit

I have seen many tutorials about face recognition, car detection using Android camera and AI Models (mlkit, TensorFlow etc) which create a rectangle shape and tell those details

but is this possible on the whole device or screen?
I mean if I get outside of that app and go to YouTube, play a video (which have cars) it will also tell me that there is a car on that video by creating a rectangle shape on that car

Here is an example image: https://i.ibb.co/P5WXkBk/car-detection.webp

I have tried these mlkit or tensorflow models but it worked only inside the app
How can I implement these on whole device I want to know that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.